# How to terminate restore process on Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, restore

I am using SharePoint 2010 on Windows server 2008 R2.

I have started a Site collection restore process.
Initially, it gave me an Error saying

> The directory C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80 is already being used by another IIS Web Sit

then it stopped restore process in the middle.Even tried restarting Server but no luck(Running from past 24 Hours, never ends)

When I try to restore with different directory it says there is already a restore process running.

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1B2CB25B9690C6E9!118&authkey=!AOaYo_mQWWeC-HA&v=3&ithint=photo%2cPNG

How do I terminate on going restore job on SP2010.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it from Central Administration.

- Go to Central admin > Monitoring > Review Timer Job Status
- Then click on Running Timer Job
- Now please see if Restore Job is running, Click and Stop it.

Comment: I dont find any Jobs running there https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1B2CB25B9690C6E9!122&authkey=!ALXRY0lS7UJFqZE&v=3&ithint=photo%2cPNG ?

Comment: on the same page click on Job definition  and then try o find one-time timer job which contains word restore.

Comment: There is no job as Restore/Backup
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1B2CB25B9690C6E9!123&authkey=!ABTuiL0-h4HbbeE&v=3&ithint=photo%2cPNG

Comment: if you filter the jobs on that page by clicking on the Schedule Type. and then see if there is any one time timer job?

Comment: Also can you share the complete error message on both cases

Comment: I find no timer job running :/ This is the error where restore process stoped and remaining are still "In Process" https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1B2CB25B9690C6E9!119&authkey=!AIAkfEeco0pG82I&v=3&ithint=photo%2cPNG

Comment: Started restore job yesterday https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1B2CB25B9690C6E9!125&authkey=!ANgizaCC0w2FL-w&ithint=folder%2c

Comment: from the one of the error, you already have a web application on Port 80,  and you trying to restore another Web application on same port...Either delete the web app or change the port number on the restore.

Comment: I tried deleting web app and changing port too but it gives error saying "already restore job in progress"

Comment: after deleteing the web app, recycle the timer job or may be reboot the server

Comment: I did restart the server, but restore job still in progress. same thing again https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1B2CB25B9690C6E9!119&authkey=!AIAkfEeco0pG82I&v=3&ithint=photo%2cPNG

Comment: run this and share the out   Get-SPWebApplication | ForEach-Object {
    $_.WebService.RunningJobs | select JobDefinitionTitle,ServerName,
        StartTime,PercentageDone,status | Format-Table -autosize}

Comment: Nothing seems to happen https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1B2CB25B9690C6E9!126&authkey=!AJFsMfkEVUULMEM&v=3&ithint=photo%2cPNG

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39029/discussion-between-ranveer-and-waqas-sarwar-mcse).